# Difficulty in a Calculator Layout in XCode in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, constraints, calculator

I'm working on a Calculator App, and all my code executes perfectly, but the only thing I am hung up on is the layout. On all phones the layout works perfectly, constraints seem to be perfect! Except for the iPhone 4, it just doesn't seem to be tall enough! It's quite frustrating as it's my first real project I've worked on and to see it stopped by something like this is annoying to say the least.

The buttons are 5 high and 4 wide, and all of them are square, and then I have a 320x50 AdMob ad at the top, with the value label inbetween.
On the 5, 6, and 6 plus there is plenty of space and everything looks perfect, but when I simulate a 4s, the distance from the ad to the buttons is dramatically reduced, so the value label is unseen. You can see what I mean from these screenshots.

**Here's a working layout:**

[image]

**And here's the problematic 4s:**

[image]

Does anyone have any ideas for a solution?

Comment: I would say it's ordinary. iPhone 4 is shorter than 5 or 6. (especially the ratio between the height/width). You might need to change the button layout on iPhone 4 in order to make it look proper. Luckily, you can do that in the IB directly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you set up the buttons, so can't give a concrete answer.

Generally, however, you can overcome the short screen dimensions by either

(1) Detecting short screen (ie window.height < 500) explicitly and change the necessary height constraints. This looks like a hack, but often works wonderfully, as iPhone 4/4S is the only exception.

Or

(2) Setting the height constraints proportional to its superview, rather than a fixed number. This may result very tall elements on tall screens, and can be mitigated with less-than-or-equal constraints and priorities.

If I were to do the calculator UI, I'd set constraints so that the five rows of buttons have the same height of 1/5 of their superview -- by creating for 4 equal-width constraints, 1 top spacing and 1 bottom spacing constraint. Then I'd create an outlet for the view that contains all the buttons, and follow either (1) or (2).

Comment: I basically have each horizontal row set to all equal widths and heights, and then the whole left column is all equal width/heights (except for the 0 button) How would I go about setting constraints proportional to the view? Does that have something to do with the 'Multiplier' option in the constraint?

Comment: @JacksonWright yes, the multiplier option is what you need. format must be 0.x

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what kind of constraints you're using, but if it works for iPhone 5+, it seems like you're doing the right thing. :-/

What I do in my apps is something like:

valueLabel.Top == ad.Bottom, so they are always touching each other and I do not set the height or width for both of them, so they can be whatever height they want. Other than that.. I do not know.